# Count Hardware Usage of Camera from other apps in Android

Tags: android

I would be glad if anyone could help me with an Android app that i am trying to make . 
Actually , there is a module in the app which counts how many time i used different service like gps ,wifi , camera etc.

So i am stuck with camera feature , how to record the usage of camera by 3rd party applications like whatsapp , instagram etc . I tried broadcast receiver on gallery , content observer on mediastore , and file manager also .

So how to do it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately your question is too broad. Try asking specific questions about programming, by splitting your problem into smaller questions. If you require tutorials and lessons, unfortunately this is not the right place. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) to detect every time that the camera is in use.

Remember to add the permission: 

 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />`

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback
import android.os.Handler

class YourClassActivity : Activity() {

    private lateinit var callback: AvailabilityCallback
    private lateinit var manager: CameraManager


    public override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        manager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        callback = object : AvailabilityCallback() {
            override fun onCameraAvailable(cameraId: String) {
                super.onCameraAvailable(cameraId)
                //Do something
            }

            override fun onCameraUnavailable(cameraId: String) {
                super.onCameraUnavailable(cameraId)
                //The camera is not available
            }
        }

        manager.registerAvailabilityCallback(callback, Handler())
    }

    public override fun onPause() {
        //Unsubscribe listener

        manager.unregisterAvailabilityCallback(callback)
         super.onPause()
    }

}
```